# trying to create a bounding box by click and drag in a web component

Tags: dart, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I am dealing with event handlers, and getting the start and end position of a mouse.

That way i can create a selection box.

I start by on mousedown, i store the current position:  `new Point(event.target.clientLeft, event.target.clientTop);` which seems to work for that location when i set the selection div accordingly.

The next step is where everything seems wrong.   While in the mousemove event, I am trying to get the coordinates of the mouse do i can use the difference to define the Height and Width of the bounding box.  It seems that everything is off by the coordinates of the web component i had created.

How should I go about this?

I have been dabbling with the event more, trying to get the position of the mouse, but i think what happens is that my start point is in reference to the webcomponent I created, and not the absolute position.

Has anyone else figured out how to do this correctly, because I have been setting things as absolute, but not correctly rendering.

As a side note, if i could subtract the absolute position of the webcomponent this is in, i think it should render the height and width correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since a PolymerElement will use HtmlElements, you will have access to a full suite of functions built into the application.  For example:

```
var top = selectedHtml.getBoundingClientRect().top - getBoundingClientRect().top + selectedHtml.clientHeight;
var left = selectedHtml.getBoundingClientRect().left - getBoundingClientRect().left + selectedHtml.clientWidth;
Point coord = new Point(left,top);
```

then you can just determine the distance from that point to get your width/height:

```
var top = selectedHtml.getBoundingClientRect().top - getBoundingClientRect().top + selectedHtml.clientHeight;
var left = selectedHtml.getBoundingClientRect().left - getBoundingClientRect().left + selectedHtml.clientWidth;
var h = top - coord.y;
var w = left - coord.x;
```

and then apply it to your Div.

```
_item.style.top = top;
_item.style.left = left;
_item.style.width = w;
_item.style.height = h;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have an easier time using global position information rather than target-relative position. You can get the global position point from a `MouseEvent` directly with `event.screen`.

Comment: The issue i was having is that when i apply it to the bounding box, the bounding box is relative to the Component it is in, not to the screen, so im trying to process that such that the offset from the Webcomponent is taken into account?

Comment: You can use `event.offset` to get the position relative to the target node.

Comment: I believe i was using offset at first, but it wasnt giving me relative to screen but relative to drive parent, which isnt what i was looking for either